# Where clause in Phoenix integration with Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-phoenix

I am trying to read some data from Phoenix to Spark using its

```
String connectionString="jdbc:phoenix:auper01-01-20-01-0.prod.vroc.com.au,auper01-02-10-01-0.prod.vroc.com.au,auper01-02-10-02-0.prod.vroc.com.au:2181:/hbase-unsecure";
Map<String, String> options2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
options2.put("driver", "org.apache.phoenix.jdbc.PhoenixDriver");
//options2.put("dbtable", url);
options2.put("table", "VROC_SENSORDATA_3");
options2.put("zkUrl", connectionString);

DataFrame phoenixFrame2 = this.hc.read().format("org.apache.phoenix.spark")
                    .options(options2)
                    .load();

System.out.println("The phoenix table is:");
phoenixFrame2.printSchema();
phoenixFrame2.show(20, false);
```

But I need to do a select with where clause, I also used the dbtable which is used for a JDBC connection in Spark but I guess it doesn't have any effect!

Based on the [documentation](http://phoenix.apache.org/phoenix_spark.html)

> "In contrast, the phoenix-spark integration is able to leverage the underlying splits provided by Phoenix in order to retrieve and save data across multiple workers. All that’s required is a database URL and a table name. Optional SELECT columns can be given, as well as pushdown predicates for efficient filtering."

But seems there is no way to parallelize the reading from Phoenix, it would be really inefficient to read the whole table in a Spark Dataframe and then doing filtering, but it seems I can find a way to apply a where clause. Does anyone know how to apply where clause in my above codes?